# why is loop not stopping in visual basic code

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a visual basic code that converts word documents into excel but the loop is not stopping and keep on writing data into excel. I'm an ETL consultant not familiar with VB code. Please help me what's wrong with this code.

```
Sub Macro1()
      Dim oTbl As Table
      Dim oRow As Row
      Dim i As Long
      Dim j As Long
      Dim xl As Object
      Set xl = CreateObject("excel.application")

      xl.workbooks.Add
      xl.Visible = True

      'Here put your path where you have your documents to read:
      myPath = "C:\Users\mukhan\"  'End with '\'
      myFile = Dir(myPath & "*.docx")

       xlRow = 1
       Do While myFile <> ""
         Documents.Open FileName:=myPath & myFile, ConfirmConversions:=False, _
           ReadOnly:=False, AddToRecentFiles:=False, PasswordDocument:="", _
           PasswordTemplate:="", Revert:=False, WritePasswordDocument:="", _
           WritePasswordTemplate:="", Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, XMLTransform:=""

        xlCol = 0
        For Each oTbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
         
         
         
         For i = 1 To oTbl.Rows.Count
            On Error Resume Next
            i = oTbl.Rows(i).Index
            If Err.Number <> 5991 Then
                With oTbl.Rows(i)
                    For j = 1 To .Cells.Count
                        With .Cells(j)
                           'do stuff
                           
                           
                                For Each r In oTbl.Rows
                                     For Each c In r.Range.Cells
                                        myText = c
                                        myText = Replace(myText, Chr(13), "")
                                        myText = Replace(myText, Chr(7), "")
                                        xlCol = xlCol + 1
                                        xl.activeworkbook.activesheet.Cells(xlRow, xlCol) = myText

                                     Next c
                                  xlRow = xlRow + 1
                                  xlCol = 0
                               Next r
                               
                        End With
                    Next j
                End With
            End If
        Next i
                               
      
         Next oTbl
                               ActiveWindow.Close False

                               myFile = Dir
      Loop

      xl.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Comment: First suggestion is get rid of "On error resume next" and find where it is crashing out and/or add a few strategic breakpoints one inside each main loop. You could also add "DoEvents" to allow you to regain control less painfully when it seizes up. Debug.Print will also allow you to follow execution and may shed some light on where it loops forever.

Comment: After `do stuff` line you have a for-each loop which repeat the whole procedure for every cell in the table.

Comment: You have 6(!!) nested loops. Are you sure this is what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim xl As Object
    Set xl = CreateObject("excel.application")
    xl.Visible = True
    
    Dim wrkBk As Object
    Set wrkBk = xl.WorkBooks.Add
    
    Dim myPath As String
    myPath = "C:\Users\mukhan\"
    
    Dim myFile As String
    myFile = Dir(myPath & "*.docx")
    
    Dim docm As Document
    Dim oTbl As Table
    Dim lRow As Long, lCol As Long
    Dim lLastRow As Long
    Do While myFile <> ""
        Set docm = Documents.Open(myPath & myFile)
        For Each oTbl In docm.Tables
            lLastRow = wrkBk.worksheets(1).Cells(1048576, 1).End(-4162).Row + 1 'Word won't understand Excel constants so -4162 = xlup
            With oTbl
                For lRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
                    For lCol = 1 To .Columns.Count
                        wrkBk.worksheets(1).Cells(lRow + lLastRow - 1, lCol) = xl.WorksheetFunction.Clean(.Cell(lRow, lCol).Range.Text)
                    Next lCol
                Next lRow
            End With
        Next oTbl
        docm.Close SaveChanges:=False
        myFile = Dir
    Loop

End Sub
```

As with Excel - set a reference to the workbook/document you're referencing rather than using the ActiveDocument/ActiveWorkbook.

The `Clean` worksheet function removes all nonprintable characters from text - not sure what Chr(7) is and not sure if it will work on Chr(13) - (Carriage Return, or is it Line Break)?